# Got my funds on an international debit card frozen trying to order on apple. What to do?

Tags: apple-id, apple-store

About 2 weeks ago, I was trying to place an order for an Macbook Air on Apple and right when it comes to pay, they refused my debit card stating that they don't accept international cards. I then tried to order the product on amazon and they refused the payment. Called the bank and they said I just made a purchase of about a thousand dollars from apple. Told them that apple declined the card so that didn't make any sense. They asked for an email of cancellation for the fund to be available again. I got on the phone with apple and they said they have no record of my debit card number within their system. I thought maybe they were some mistake in the number or something so I tried the live chat for more accuracy (since english is not my first language) but they said live chat wasn't available to my location (Haiti).

I see no way to contact apple other than by phone and it's expensive and ineffective for me. The bank told me it could take as long as 3 months for the fund to be available again and I can't wait that much to get the computer since I need it for work.

What to do? How can I get an apple representative to follow through with me or at least get that cancellation email the bank is asking for? Or least have an email address where I can address the issue?

Comment: [Apple contact numbers around the world](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201232) other than that, there's nothing anyone on SE can do.

Answer (score 1):

Debit card holds are notoriously hard to deal with.

Contacting your bank is really the only way to release a hold. Even if a reputable vendor releases a hold, the banking system is designed to not act quickly to rescind the transaction as they time out once the several week period elapses.

Hopefully you have a good relation with your bank as they can immediately release your funds to you based on your relationship.

You can always reach an Apple representative via phone or email via the web site at which you made the order. Presumably you still have the web order number or can call the US number if you're totally lost:

- http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201232